# JAVACV videocapture read stops taking new pictures and just repeats the same one, why is it doing this?

Tags: java, opencv

I am currently using the Java Open Cv Library to take a series of consecutive images from a camera. The frame that is captured is then passed to another thread which saves the image.
   But, for some reason after it takes a certain amount it stops taking new images and instead just repeats the previous one.

If i ask it to take 10 it stops at 5, and for 20 it stops at 11, so it isn't the same value each time.

The code is currently inside of a thread but i do not think that this is affecting it in any way.

Here is the current code.

```
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
        camera.open(0);

        Mat frame = new Mat();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            camera.read(frame);


            fileName = "Captures/" + timetoNano + ".png";
            fileTime = timetoNano;
            fileToSave = frame;

            ImageProperties newProperties = new ImageProperties(fileName,
                    fileToSave, fileTime);
            bufferImageProps.add(newProperties);
        }
```

If i put camera.open(0) inside of the for loop, this does fix the issue, it does however decrease performance greatly and i don't think it has to be there as it works up until this "breaking point".

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found the solution. I moved the line

```
Mat frame = new Mat();
```

Inside of the for loop.

Because of this it means that each time you capture a frame you are capturing it onto a null frame, this seems to fix the issue.